# Swipe right to dismiss edge size

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

Is it possible to increase edge size `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` of UINavigationController reacts user touches?

I.e. is it possible to make swipe right from middle of screen to move and pop current top Viewcontroller same way as from the left screen edge?

Comment: you can try PAN gesture recognizer for this

Answer (score 1):

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeRight.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeLeft.direction = .left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    }

    // you can track all direction swipe like below, and to do that first you have to add gesture in the view you want to track.
    @objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case .right:
                // push pop here
                print("Swiped right")
            case .down:
                print("Swiped down")
            case .left:
                // push pop here
                print("Swiped left")
            case .up:
                print("Swiped up")
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but main problem is how to handle this left to right gesture with same animation as default swipe to dismiss. Moving view edge to the touch location and dismissing or moving view back depending on touch up position and velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found a solution to increase the edge touch size using this library: [SwipeTransition](https://github.com/tattn/SwipeTransition)